# How to add static ipv6 route with systemd-networkd

Tags: ipv6, systemd-networkd

I'm trying to achieve the equivalent of the ip command below via networkd without success.

```
ip route add default via fe80::1 dev eth0
```

My networkd configuration looks like below and brings up the network successfully apart from the default ipv6 routing. I've tried adding and removing GatewayOnLink=yes without any success. Running the command above after startup brings up ipv6 connectivity but I would prefer to do this via networkd configuration.

```
/etc/systemd/network/00-eth0.network
----

[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
DHCP=no
DNS=8.8.8.8

[Address]
Label=static-ipv4
Address=X.X.X.X/32
Peer=Y.Y.Y.Y

[Address]
Label=static-ipv6
Address=X:X:X:X::1/64

[Route]
Gateway=fe80::1
Gateway=Y.Y.Y.Y
GatewayOnlink=yes
```

This is for a Hetzner cloud server, I don't have any other IPV6 enabled machines to rule out something specific about their setup. Systemd is version 238 running on coreos.

Comment: ok, not sure how relevant it is :) Other than the ipv6 routing all the configuration in the file is being applied.

Comment: Try removing the `[Address]` and `[Route]` headings and see if that works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have two `Gateway` directives in one `[Route]` block.

From reference: https://systemd.network/systemd.network.html#%5BRoute%5D%20Section%20Options

> Specify several "`[Route]`" sections to configure several routes.

This is what works for me:

```
[Route]
Gateway=fe80::1
GatewayOnLink=yes

[Route]
Gateway=Y.Y.Y.Y
GatewayOnLink=yes
```

This way the first block adds a default IPv6 routing entry, equivalent to

```bsh
ip -6 route add default via fe80::1 proto static
```

If you for whatever reason don't want the `proto static` part, add `Proto=boot` to the networkd configuration (it's the default for iproute2).

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer I'm hoping to accept since it involves configuration outside networkd, but it does bring my IPv6 routing up reliably:

```
~ $ cat /etc/systemd/system/ipv6-routing.service 
[Unit]
Description=Setup ipv6 routing
After=network-online.target
Requires=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ip route add default via fe80::1 dev eth0
RemainAfterExit=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```